# Difference between running 2 threads and running 2 classes calling same function

Tags: java, redis, lettuce

I am exploring blocking read commands on Redis Steram [XREAD and XADD]. Using XREAD we can acquire multi-client blocking read which is released when XADD is executed. [This](https://paluch.biz/blog/174-a-first-look-at-redis-streams-and-how-to-use-them-with-java.html)

I am observing the following 2 different behaviour:

Case : 1

```
public static void main(String[] args){

        Runnable t1 = new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                function_to_read_block();
            }
        };
        Runnable t2 = new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                function_to_read_block();
            }
        };
       new Thread(t1).start();
       new Thread(t2).start();
}
```

In this case, the lock acquired is released when **2 XADD** commands are executed on redis-cli.

vs

Case : 2

```
public class ClassA {
     
     public static void main(String[] args){
          function_to_read_block()
     }
}

public class ClassB {
     
     public static void main(String[] args){
          function_to_read_block()
     }
}
```

Running both classes simultaneously, **1 XADD** command releases both the read locks at once.
[This is the ideal behaviour I was expecting from Case 1 as well]

Can someone explain why is there a difference in these 2 cases? How is running 2 thread different from running 2 separate classes calling the same function simultaneously??

For redis, I am using lettuce library. [Synchronous RedisCluster Connection]

Comment: Do not know about xadd or xread but in case 2 you are basically launching two separate applications. So both have different application context/stack. So, As these two are two separate  apps, they never know about each other and never block i.e run simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

As i know for running 2 class in same time , you have to use 2 threads ,
so in case 2 , they are running in following  each others ,also your code in case 2 , is not starting , you need function call also..